# Session validation in Rest-API [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed]

Tags: java, rest, session, jackson

I'm new to `Rest-API` and trying to figure out session validations. For my application, I have the concept of session and session time-out. If the user session is invalid or timed-out, then I'm checking the session and returning the error message. Code is as written below.

```
@GET
@Path("/getScreenDetails")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getScreenDetails(@BeanParam RequestBean requestBean) {

    HttpSession currentSession = (HttpSession) InitialiseHelper
            .getSessionMap().get(
                    requestBean.getRequest().getSession().getId());
    if (currentSession == null) {
        // user has not logged in needs to throw and error.
        String errorMessage = "Invalid session ";
        return ResponseHelper.getErrorResponse(103, errorMessage,
                AAConstants.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED_401);
    }
    //Do operations:
    }
```

But I'm getting

`[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed]`

with root cause

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed error.`

I'm getting the IllegalStateException error in the first line.

```
HttpSession currentSession = (HttpSession) InitialiseHelper
            .getSessionMap().get(
                    requestBean.getRequest().getSession().getId());
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you cannot start a session when content has already been sent to the requester.

This means that if you intent to use Session, start them as soon as possible, and before you output anything back to the user.
Given that we cannot read the rest of your class, it becomes harder to help further. If possible, edit your question with the response method you are using.